# Access the WSO2 Carbon Registry over WebDAV

Tags: webdav, wso2

Is it possible to publish the registry of a Carbon based server (e.g. a stock wso2-carbon-3.2.3 platform or a wso2esb-4.0.3 where additional features were added via the Feature Manager) as a WebDAV resource?

If I understand correctly, this is possible for the Governance Registry. If it is not possible to publish the 'normal' Carbon registry and I would have to install the Governance Registry:

- is it possible to run the G. Reg. inside the same carbon instance?
- can I use postgresql as the backend of that carbon instance even if I install additional products e.g. Gov. Registry, Application Server, Data Services Server etc.?
- if I install necessary features with the feature manager, do I also have to set up their DB schema by importing an SQL script? if yes, where do I find that script?
- if there is specific configuration to be performed for the GREG after installing it as a feature?

I know there is a lot of documentation but I am currently at a loss regarding these specific aspects. I know how to add a feature, but I didn't find a concise description like "to install IS, selected feature x + y + z". Is there such a documentation somewhere?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: it is possible to install the WebDAV feature on top of a stock Carbon installation; it is not necessary to use the Governance Registry. To do so, one has to install the following features

- Registry Webdav
- Registry WS API

Follow these instructions to install them:

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon401/Installing+Features

Use the URL of the carbon repository which matches your product's Carbon version. In my case, it is Carbon 4.0.1:

```
http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.1
```

After installing those features (I don't remember whether a restart of the server was necessary), you should be able to mount the registry with this URL:

```
mount -t davfs https://<carbon-server-ip>:<carbon-server-https-port>/registry/resourcewebdav /mnt/carbon-registry
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's few more useful links about mounting registry as WebDAV.

- http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/WebDAV+Sample
- http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Using+WebDAV+on+Windows
- http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Using+WebDAV+on+Linux

About your question regarding Feature installation, WSO2 Carbon 4.0 based products support Feature Installation grouped by category.[image: Features Grouped by Category]
HTH